# C# Thread safe random long for use in Visual Studio Load Test

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio, load-testing

I'm using Visual Studio Load Test (Enterprise) to perform API load tests through REST calls. One of the endpoints I'm testing needs a unique long value for each POST in the range of 100000000000000 to 999999999999999.

As Visual Studio Load Test threads requests, using random generators that base the seed of the system clock causes alot of duplicates (for 4000 random numbers over 60 seconds I'm seeing several hundred duplicates).

Does anyone know how i can implement a random generator thats thread safe for use in Visual Studio Load test?

Comment: Wrap it in a class with a lock?

Comment: `lastValue + 1` why use random?

Comment: Yeah, I missed the word "unique" in there, random is not usable at all, there is no guarantee that the Random class will deliver unique values, in fact it is pretty much guaranteed that you will get duplicates.

Comment: Showing your code would be great here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a static variable and increase its value for each request.

Comment: You might add `locking`

Answer (score 0):

Rather than random, if all you need is different numbers then you can use the context value `$WebTestIteration`. If more than one agent is used then you could use something such as `$WebTestIteration * numberOfAgents + $AgentId`. Of course two these values are in the context so the expression is more like

```
int.Parse(e.WebTest.Context["$WebTestIteration"]) * numberOfAgents
    + int.Parse(e.WebTest.Context["$AgentId")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with [Interlocked](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Interlocked.Increment(ref longCount);
```